# Dual OS (Linux & WIndows)

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

I have windows 10 installation in C drive and linux(Ubuntu) in D drive.

Now when I am on windows and try to access D drive it asks me to format the drive. The linux partition(D drive) is formatted by ext4.

How can I stop windows asking to format or is there any way to hide D drive when I am on Windows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Linux doesn't use letters for partitions and there's no reason for Windows to try to read the Ubuntu partition unless you explicitly gave it a letter when it shouldn't have.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. When I am on windows and try to access D drive which is a linux ext4 drive it asks me to format.

Comment: Ah ok I got it. So I need to change/remove the letter of D drive and it will be hidden.Thank you.